# Angularjs directive to add a class to form inputs on form's submit event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using `ng-class` to add `submitted` class to my inputs when form is submitted like

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
<input name= "input1" ng-class="{'submitted':myform.$submitted}" ng-model=data.input1/>
.....
....
</form>
```

Although it gets the job done but it is too verbose and I have many inputs where I need this. I want to create a directive to make my html look like

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
<input name= "input1" set-submitted ng-model=data.input1/>
.....
....
</form>
```

How can I create a directive for this purpose?

Comment: Why not add class to form itself in only one place instead of all elements?

Comment: Frankly, I just wanted to know how I can create a directive for this particular purpose. yes you are right about adding class to the form and `ng-submitted` class is automatically added to the form when it is submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to simply use `ng-submitted` class that is automatically set on form by Angular on form submit.

However for academic purposes here is a simple directive to set class on elements itself:

```
app.directive('setSubmitted', function() {
    return {
        require: '^form',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngFormController) {
            scope.$watch(function() { 
                return ngFormController.$submitted;
            }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    element.toggleClass('submitted', newVal);
                }
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: can u please explain second argument to `toggleClass`?

Comment: does this function comes from jquery or its core angular?

Comment: This is a method of [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), implementation of jQuery's [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method. The second boolean argument determines if the class should be added (`true`) or removed (`false`). You could also use `if` block with `addClass` and `removeClass`.